# How to stop motion in a Flatlist in react Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, infinite-scroll

I would like to know if there is any possible way to stop the motion of the FlatList even if the user is not touching the screen. I just want to make the implemention like Facebook does in the feed news, I am currently using `onEndReach`  in order to fetch more data, but if the user scroll really fast the motion keep going and going, that's why I need to stop the motion when the final is reached.

Comment: would passing `bounces={false}` to your `FlatList` component give you the result you are trying for?

Comment: `bounces={false}` it will work just on iOS in my case I would like to solve the solution for both platforms. Because bounce just keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property that handle the motion when the user is scrolling and it is `pagingEnabled` which might help you on iOS version. But in my particular case it was a that in the FlatList there was a wrapper, and cause that weird behavior.